# SQLite returning records in random order

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am working on an `android` survey application and I am using `SQLite` for saving the data and each survey can have multiple questions. As I want to keep the order of questions same as it was during the creation of survey so all the questions gets stored in the `database` in the same order. Now, the problem is when I try to fetch these questions by passing `surveyId`, I get the questions in a random order. I want to get the questions from database in the same order as they are stored. For example, if "My question 1" is the first question in the survey then I should get it first in the `cursor` but the `cursor` returned by the `select` statement has all the questions in a random order.

Query:

```
SQLiteDatabase writableDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        return writableDatabase.rawQuery("select * from " + SURVEY_TABLE + " inner join " + EMOJI_TABLE + " inner join " +
                QUESTIONS_TABLE + " where survey_table.survey_id = " + surveyId + " and emoji_table.survey_id = " + surveyId +
                " and questions_table.survey_id = " + surveyId, null);
```

Above query returns me questions which are not in the same order as they are in the database.

Comment: The database design doesn't guarantee there will be any ordering of rows in the output UNLESS you've specified an "order by" condition in select statement. So you need to add "Order by" part to your query

Comment: @ekochergin Yes I know but I am not sure if I can use ORDER BY because I don't have any column on which I can use it.

Comment: then you should add it. Just add a question_id or question_num or something sort of that.